# Windows Phone Emulator is unable to send touch data

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I would appreciate any help with the following issue with the windows emulator for android which occurs when I am working on a xamarin project.

A dialog box appears:

**Windows phone Emulator is unable to send touch data:The device closed the connection. Some functions may not be available.**

I can close this dialog but the emulator is unresponsive, I cannot even use the hardware emulated buttons. The emulator doesn't close and I have to kill the process.

Looks as though this may have something to do with switching mouse focus between VS and back to the emulator, when for example debugging. The issue arises next time I try to gain focus/or use touch in the app.

The problem is intermittent but frequent.

Should add that when restarting the emulator from within VS results in a deployment issue so I have to restart it from the Device Profile Listing.